# How to handle subscription in Meteor / Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router, subscription

whats the bestway to handle subscription based data. For example, you have a game where you have to create the character first before you can do any other things. Currently I thougth I can try to handle it with a `onBeforeAction` filter. So I have a global controller for every route that needs a the character.

```
DefaultController = LayoutController.extend({
  onBeforeAction : function() {
    var currentCharacter = Character.getCurrent.call({});
    if(currentCharacter === undefined) {
        this.render('CharacterCreate');
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
 },
 waitOn() {
    this.subscribe('characters.owned');
 }
});
```

You have a route like this:

```
Router.route('/game', { controller: 'DefaultController' });
```

The problem is until the the collection is loaded the game template will shown. Is there a better approach like this? And another problem when a route needs a character it throws an exception until the subscription is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a loading hook while the subscriptions are being loaded.

```
loading(){
  this.render('myLoadingTemplate');
}
```

The `loading` hook is run automatically while waiting for subscriptions to be ready.

You might find [my post on building a clean router.js file](http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/08/meteor-build-clean-easy-to-maintain.html) useful.